# Why GZIP utility cares about extension?

Tags: compression, gzip

Whenever I need to decompress a file which was compressed with Gzip, I need to rename the file with a `.gz` extension , I tried other compression utility like `zip, bzip2` and they don't seem to care about extensions. Why is this is the case with `Gzip` , isn't just checking magic numbers to identify a type of file or by others means would be useful right?
Or is it like this for a purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the general idea is that you can run

```
gunzip *
```

and it will use the file extension as a first filter; as described in the man page:

> `gunzip` takes a list of files on its command line and replaces each file whose name ends with `.gz`,  `-gz`,  `.z`,  `-z`,  or  `_z`
> (ignoring  case) and which begins with the correct magic number with an uncompressed file without the original extension.
> `gunzip` also recognizes the special extensions `.tgz` and `.taz` as shorthands for `.tar.gz` and `.tar.Z` respectively.  When compressing, `gzip` uses the `.tgz` extension if necessary instead of truncating a file with a `.tar` extension.

Another significant feature of `gunzip` is that it ignores the name stored in the compressed file by default, and extracts to a file whose name is determined by removing the suffix from the file to be decompressed; it can’t do that if the file doesn’t have a known suffix.

Of course filtering using only the magic number would have a similar effect when handling multiple files, but there are a couple of differences:

- files with a non-`gzip` extension which aren’t readable by the current user wouldn’t necessarily cause errors (but they currently do, because `gunzip` opens files even if it’s not going to try to decompress them);
- avoiding the need to check the magic number in every file would have saved a lot of time back when `gzip` was implemented.

Now that it’s documented in this fashion, it can’t easily be changed (although the `gzip` maintainers have recently demonstrated their willingness to introduce significant changes in behaviour, *e.g.* with `gunzip -l`).

Comment: Ok, But whats the point with a file in which read permission stripped off? However gzip will throw an error as permission denied , right?

Comment: In a shared directory, there could be files which the current user can’t read. But that point is moot because as you say, `gunzip` still complains about the permissions (even though it doesn’t need to).